# Check if user completed email verification ReactJS Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication, email-verification

I have the following code which helps sign up users. Currently trying to integrate email verification and execute the updateProfile callback once that is completed. I'm able to send email using the .sendEmailVerification() method but can't figure how to make the check and execute the other codes. Would appreciate any help on this!

```
export default function SignUp() {
  const history = useHistory();
  const { firebase } = useContext(FirebaseContext);

  const [firstName, setFirstName] = useState('');
  const [emailAddress, setEmailAddress] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [error, setError] = useState('');

  const isInvalid = firstName === '' || password === '' || emailAddress === '';

  const handleSignup = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    return firebase
      .auth()
      .createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailAddress, password)
      .then((result) =>
        result.user
          //.sendEmailVerification()
          .updateProfile({
            displayName: firstName,
            photoURL: Math.floor(Math.random() * 5) + 1,
          })
          .then(() => {
            history.push(ROUTES.BROWSE);
          })
      )
      .catch((error) => {
        setFirstName('');
        setEmailAddress('');
        setPassword('');
        setError(error.message);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to overthink it. When creating an account (`createUserWithEmailAndPassword`), create another key in the firebase object that flags the user with an unverified state

```js
{
    email: '',
    password: '',
    verified: false
}
```

After the user clicks on the verification URL and it is a success, flag it as true.

```js
{
    email: '',
    password: '',
    verified: true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

there is already a property on the user to handle this.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User#emailverified